# Is it possible to generate a database from the Entity Data Model (edmx) file?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

In Linq to SQL it is possible to generate the database from the dbml file.

Is it possible to generate a database from the Entity Data Model ?  I wish to accomplish the same thing using the edmx file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not until the next version, as you can read on the Entity Framework Design blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2008/09/10/model-first.aspx